# Order an unordered array of numbers from 1-8, so that the end and starting integers are alternated eg [8,1,7,2,6,3,5,4,]

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

I'm a newbie to all of this and trying to improve myself by solving problems and challenges.

I came across a problem whereby I have an unordered array which contains 8 integers.

eg [2,3,1,4,6,5,8,7]

I need to sort it [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and reorder the array so that the array starts with the end value and then the first value and so on eg [8,1,7,2,6,3,5,4,]

I worked out I could use map() to iterate across the array and then use push() with pop() and shift() however it leaves the last 2 numbers behind in the original array and I'm not sure why. I got around this by using a concat and a reverse but I still don't understand why pop and shift don't bring across all the elements.

**Code below that doesn't pull all the elements:**

```
  const reorder = (array) => {
    let store = []
    array.sort((a, b) => a - b).map((item, i) => {
        if (array) {
            store.push(array.pop())
            store.push(array.shift())
        }
    })
    return store
}


reorder([2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7]) // returns [8,1,7,2,6,3]
```

**Code that works but I have to add a concat and a reverse:**

```
const reorder = (array) => {
    let store = []
    array.sort((a, b) => a - b).map((item, i) => {
        if (array) {
            store.push(array.pop())
            store.push(array.shift())

        }
    })
    return store.concat(array.reverse()) 
}

reorder([2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7]) //returns [8,1,7,2,6,3,5,4]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please spend some time to improve the indentation (before posting a question)

Comment: Why do you use map function? You didn't use item and i at all

Comment: @Andreas good point and updated code so its more readable.

Comment: @LearningMathematics thanks and very true,I'm still a newbie so would welcome an alternative solution or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've seen nobody explained why the original OP solution doesn't work, Here is why:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/

> Map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values (including undefined).
>
> It is **not** called for missing elements of the array; that is:
>
> > 1.Indexes that have never been set;
> >
> > 2.**which have been deleted**; or
> >
> > 3.which have never been assigned a value.

So what is happening in our code is that:
On the first iteration,
`[(2), 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7]`
Map picks the first element(2) in the array, and delete the first and last characters in the array, so the array becomes

`[3,(1), 4, 6, 5, 8]`
Now, as map will not consider deleted elements, the second element(1) in the current array is called, also the first and last element in also removed:

`[1, 4,(6), 5]`
Now, map is trying to find the third element(6), and delete the first and last element:

`[4,6]`
Now, map is trying to find the fourth element, which is out of bound, so the map function will terminate.

So, you are strongly advised not to use `Array.prototype.shift` or `Array.prototype.pop` in `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: That is the perfect explanation and totally answers why I shouldn't have used map(). Only difference is I sorted the array beforehand but the principle is the same as per your answer that pop and shift delete and map doesn't recognise deletions so moves onto the next item until it runs out of options.  I should have used a for loop I guess. Thanks very much for taking the time to explain it to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would just bisect the array, sort them in opposite orders and then add each element from each array to a new array

Given that you want to then take the sorted bisected arrays and produce another single array, I'd then use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const alternatingSort = function (array) {
    array = array.sort();
    const midpoint = Math.round(array.length / 2)
    let arr1 = array.slice(0, midpoint);
    let arr2 = array.slice(midpoint);
    arr2 = arr2.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });

    return arr1.reduce(function (retVal, item, index) {
        arr2[index] && retVal.push(arr2[index]);
        retVal.push(item);
        return retVal;
    }, []);
}
console.log(alternatingSort([2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8, 7]));
console.log(alternatingSort([2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 8])); // with odd number
```

Comment: thanks, nice solution , I really need to brush up again on reduce() and using the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way:

```js
const reorder = (array) => {
  array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const result = [];
  const length = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      result.push(array.pop());
    } else {
      result.push(array.shift());
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const result = reorder([2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 7]);
console.log(result);
```

Notice that I've intentionally made the array length to be an odd number. Some of the solutions here will break if the length is an odd number.

Comment: For example, OP's first solution.

Comment: I didn't think to use modular in the index. Thanks thats pretty straight forward for me to understand :-)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would sort, split in half and then just insert in. Not very fancy, but gets the job done.

```js
function strangeWeave (arr) {
  var sorted = arr.slice().sort()
  var result = sorted.splice(0,Math.floor(sorted.length/2))
  for (let i=0;sorted.length;i+=2) {
    result.splice(i,0,sorted.pop())
  }
  return result
}

console.log(strangeWeave([1,2]))
console.log(strangeWeave([1,2,3]))
console.log(strangeWeave([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
console.log(strangeWeave([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, nice and straight forward

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier solution to sort two different arrays, one normal and one in reverse, then connect them together. Here is the code for that:

```js
var myArray = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8];

function getCopy(arr) {
var x = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  x.push(arr[i]);
  
return x;
}
function sortMyWay(arr) {

  var sortedArr = [],   
      leftSide = getCopy(arr).sort()
                 .splice(0, Math.ceil(arr.length / 2)),
      rightSide = getCopy(arr).sort().reverse()
                  .splice(0, Math.floor(arr.length / 2));
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    i % 2 
    ? sortedArr.push(leftSide[Math.floor(i / 2)]) 
    : sortedArr.push(rightSide[Math.floor(i / 2)]);    
  console.log(sortedArr);
return sortedArr;
}
var sortedArr = sortMyWay(myArray);
```

Hope it helped!

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, it did help and I think I've been missing the modular  in my code, I'm going to have a play around tomorrow :-)

Comment: @epixme I'm glad I could've helped you! Happy coding! :)